# Input event listener not firing for classes

Tags: javascript

I have a CSS class for 3 input boxes, called `.rgb`. In this `.rgb` class are three input boxes with ID's of: `#rgb`, `#rgb2` and `#rgb3`.

I am trying to capture when any of the three input boxes have text inputted using `.addEventListener` although it isn't working when I select the elements by class name. No innerHTML is being appended

Below is my minified code for this example:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('rgb').addEventListener("input", function() {
    // Stores the r, g, b values
    var r = document.getElementById('rgb').value;
    var g = document.getElementById('rgb2').value;
    var b = document.getElementById('rgb3').value;

    document.getElementById('rgb-output').innerHTML = 'RGB: rgb(' + r + ', ' + g + ', ' + b + ')';
    document.getElementById('hex-output').innerHTML = 'HEX: ' + rgbToHEX(r, g, b).toUpperCase();
}, false);
```

How can I modify the code so that it listens for input on all three input boxes under the `.rgb` class?

Comment: If you open the debug console you'll see an error. `addEventListener` is a method on an element. `getElementsByClassName` returns a `NodeList` (think of it like an array).

Comment: You can't use `addEventListener` on `document.getElementsByClassName` since it returns an array of DOM Elements (loop on those) + `input` might not be the event you're looking for but `change` or `blur`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result of `getElementsByClassName` is a node-list. You can't attach an event handler to a node list. You have to go into the node list and attach the handlers to the individual elements stored in that node list.

```js
    var theInputs = document.querySelectorAll('.rgb')
    for(var i = 0; i < theInputs.length; ++i){
      theInputs[i].addEventListener("input", calc);
    }

    function calc() {
       // Stores the r, g, b values
       var r = document.getElementById('rgb').value;
       var g = document.getElementById('rgb2').value;
       var b = document.getElementById('rgb3').value;

       document.getElementById('rgb-output').innerHTML = 'RGB: rgb(' + r + ', ' + g + ', ' + b + ')';
       document.getElementById('hex-output').innerHTML = 'HEX: ' + rgbToHEX(r, g, b).toUpperCase();
    }

    function rgbToHEX(){ 
      return "it works!";
    }
```

```html
<input class="rgb" id="rgb">
<input class="rgb" id="rgb2">
<input class="rgb" id="rgb3">

<div id="rgb-output"></div>
<div id="hex-output"></div>
```

Comment: Perfect! Ill accept this in a few mins when I can. I didn't realise that it stored the values in a node list